# build.gradle and Manifest files are missing?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

So this might be a really stupid question, but I'm a total beginner so bear with me. I made a project in Unity, then downloaded the SDK and NDK stuff so that I could build for Android. After a lot of troubleshooting, I've determined that I need to make changes to either my build.gradle or Manifest files (or both) for a project, but I can't find either one anywhere. I've tried the search function in Android Studio as well as looking through folders manually and came up empty-handed both times. Aren't these files supposed to be there somewhere automatically? I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. [image: A]

Comment: Share  ur project structure screenshot

Comment: Click on the "Project" and see u have "Android" option to select there. This project seems to be a non Android project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was that I never properly imported my project, so it didn't have those files in the first place. Thank you to everyone for your help, though!

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio you can press the Shift key in quick succession (twice) and that will allow you to access the files in your project. From that dialog, try searching for build.gradle or your Manifest. It's the quickest way (that I know of, at least) to get to a file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

When you create Android Studio Project at that time it will create Manifest and build.gradle and many more files for a particular project.

Your Manifest File Location is

```
YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/app/src/main/AndroidManifest
```

There are 2 type of build.gradle files are in your project directory, which is App Leval and Second is Project Leval.

```
1. YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY
2. YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/app
```

Comment: Such a location doesn't seem to appear anywhere in my project (see the screenshot I added).

Comment: Change From Project to Android type Directory, there you can see the your folders and files

Answer (score 0):

Try re-importing the project to Android Studio.

Select the build.gradle file in the android project folder and then click import.